# Howto wait for query execution on database?

Tags: node.js, sqlite, callback

my code is:

```
        jsonArray.forEach(function (that) {
            db.each(sql, function (err, row) {
            }, function (err, rows) {
                console.log("111");
            });
        });
        console.log("222");
```

after running first write is 222.
How to wait for db.each to write 111 then 222?
thanks

**EDITED:**

`console.log("222");` is after loop.

Comment: Have a look at async.js and its eachSeries function

Comment: why can't you place that line inside the callback itself ? i mean after console.log("111"); ?

Comment: Hi @Robin, `console.log("222");` is after loop.

Comment: @hahamed No, it isn't after the loop, it's before it. the loop doesn't happen until after the query is complete.

Comment: I edited my code. I want 222 be writed at end of all 111.

Answer (score 2):

In order to make sure "222" is logged after "111", you'd have to do this:

```
jsonArray.forEach(function (that) {
    db.each(sql, function (err, row) {
    }, function (err, rows) {
        console.log("111");
        console.log("222");
    });
});
```

This is because the second function passed to `db.each()` is guaranteed to be called *after* the DB query has completed. Since the DB query is performed *asynchronously*, you cannot log "222" right after you initiate the query and expect it to reliably show up after "111".

Now, if you actually wanted "111" to print out with every result row, you want something like this:

```
jsonArray.forEach(function (that) {
    db.each(sql, function (err, row) {
        console.log("111");
    }, function (err, rows) {
        console.log("222");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanx @cybersam. but I edited my code. I want 222 be writed at end of all 111.

Comment: What do you mean by 'all "111"'? You should only see a single "111" with your original code. See my updated answer for what you would do to see "111" with every result row.

Comment: 111 is in loop. i want when loop finish then write 222. i edited my code.